# ¿Cómo poner un botón en un datatable dinámicamente con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables, datatable

Tengo una mini pagina que me muestra los datos que están almacenados en un array tipo objeto en *JavaScript* quiero crear un botón al final de mi *HTML* dinámicamente con datatable pero en lugar del botón me sale lo siguiente:

> [object HTMLButtonElement]

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <title>chiquiProyecto</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Registro procedimientos odontológicos</h1>
        <p>Este documento va anexado a la historia clinica odontologica del paciente</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container border-0 text-center">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="tablaPacientes">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre paciente</th>                    
                    <th>Tipo documento</th>
                    <th>Numero documento</th>
                    <th>Fecha consulta</th>
                    <th>Detalle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="cuerpoTabla">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<br>
<br>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="misJS/chiquiproyecto2.js"> </script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi código *JavaScript* el cual crea el botón y lo añade a la ultima posición de cada fila del *array*:

```
var array =
    [["oscar Benavidez", "c.c", 765454676, "12-03-2018"],
    ["fernando gonzales", "c.c", 897858467, "02-07-2018"],
    ["santiago mendez", "c.c", 125457878, "15-01-2019"],
    ["luisa manrrique", "c.c", 78758744, "28-02-2019"],
    ["pedro higuera", "c.c", 988957874, "15-04-2020"],
    ["luis amador", "c.c", 34478304, "16-07-2918"]
    ];
const tBody = document.getElementById('cuerpoTabla');
i = -1;
for (const fila of array) {
    i = i + 1
    var crearFila = document.createElement('tr')
    crearFila.setAttribute('id','fila'+i)
    tBody.appendChild(crearFila)
    j=-1;
    var ponerDato = document.getElementById('fila'+i)
    var boton = document.createElement("button");
    boton.innerHTML = 'ver';
    fila.push(boton);
    // ponerDato.appendChild(boton);
    for (const iterator of fila) {
        j=j+1;
        var crearColumna = document.createElement('td');
        crearColumna.setAttribute('id','columna'+j);
        crearColumna.textContent = iterator;
        ponerDato.appendChild(crearColumna);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tablaPacientes').DataTable();
});
```

Agradezco la ayuda al que se tome la molestia de mirar mi código y decirme como convierto ese objeto en el botón que necesito, muchas gracias.

Comment: En la [documentación](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) te dice cómo lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo dijo Triby dentro de su documentación dice como hacerlo, te dejo el ejemplo en tu código.

Igual creo haber visto tu error, y acomodado tu código, revísalo, igual lo que hago es después de poner en la ultima fila la columna, agrego una con el btn, de igual manera creo que es mas simple hacerlo con la documentación.

```js
var array = [
  ["oscar Benavidez", "c.c", 765454676, "12-03-2018"],
  ["fernando gonzales", "c.c", 897858467, "02-07-2018"],
  ["santiago mendez", "c.c", 125457878, "15-01-2019"],
  ["luisa manrrique", "c.c", 78758744, "28-02-2019"],
  ["pedro higuera", "c.c", 988957874, "15-04-2020"],
  ["luis amador", "c.c", 34478304, "16-07-2918"]
];
const tBody = document.getElementById('cuerpoTabla');
i = -1;
for (const fila of array) {
  i = i + 1
  var crearFila = document.createElement('tr')
  crearFila.setAttribute('id', 'fila' + i)
  tBody.appendChild(crearFila)
  j = -1;
  var ponerDato = document.getElementById('fila' + i)
  
  for (const iterator of fila) {
    j = j + 1;
    var crearColumna = document.createElement('td');
    crearColumna.setAttribute('id', 'columna' + j);
    crearColumna.textContent = iterator;
    ponerDato.appendChild(crearColumna);
  }
    var crearColumna = document.createElement('td');
    crearColumna.setAttribute('id', 'columna' + j+1);
    var boton = document.createElement('button');
    boton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ver!"+fila[0]));
    crearColumna.appendChild(boton);
    ponerDato.appendChild(crearColumna);
  
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#tablaPacientes').DataTable();
  });
  
  
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#tablaPacientes').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": -1,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-dark '>Documento</button>"
    }]
  });

  $('#tablaPacientes tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    alert(data[0] + " Tiene documento Nro: " + data[2]);
  });


});
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>chiquiProyecto</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Registro procedimientos odontológicos</h1>
    <p>Este documento va anexado a la historia clinica odontologica del paciente</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container border-0 text-center">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="tablaPacientes">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre paciente</th>
          <th>Tipo documento</th>
          <th>Numero documento</th>
          <th>Fecha consulta</th>
          <th>Detalle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="cuerpoTabla">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```